# jQuery.event.props is undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using [jquery.event.move](https://github.com/stephband/jquery.event.move) to create move events on touch devices. 
The script is throwing an error on line 580.

```
570 // Make jQuery copy touch event properties over to the jQuery event
571 // object, if they are not already listed. But only do the ones we
572 // really need. IE7/8 do not have Array#indexOf(), but nor do they
573 // have touch events, so let's assume we can ignore them.
574 if (typeof Array.prototype.indexOf === 'function') {
575     (function(jQuery, undefined){
576         var props = ["changedTouches", "targetTouches"],
577             l = props.length;
578         
579         while (l--) {
580             if (jQuery.event.props.indexOf(props[l]) === -1) {
581                 jQuery.event.props.push(props[l]);
582             }
583         }
584     })(jQuery);
585 };
```

When it gets to line 580 it throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`
The way I understand it is that jQuery.event.props is undefined? Shouldn't this array be present by default in jquery? 
I've "installed" jQuery in my rails app as a gem (jquery-rails 4.1.1)
Any idea what I could do?

Comment: Are you using jQuery version 3 or above?

Comment: I'm using jquery-rails 4.1.1

Comment: $.fn.jquery returns 3.1.0, so I guess that's the version I'm running

Comment: There is an issue with v 3 or above as mentioned in [jQuery 3.0.0 breaks jQuery.event.props usage](https://github.com/stephband/jquery.event.move/issues/31). No solution provided yet for that, so try to use any version below 3 and test again.

Comment: That was it, if you write it as an answer I'll accept it palash
Where did you find any information about this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an issue with jquery version 3 or above as mentioned in the [`jquery.event.move`](https://github.com/stephband/jquery.event.move) github [issue](https://github.com/stephband/jquery.event.move/issues) page:

[**jQuery 3.0.0 breaks `jQuery.event.props` usage**](https://github.com/stephband/jquery.event.move/issues/31)

This happened since in jQuery 3.0.0 upgrade `jQuery.event.props` and `jQuery.event.fixHooks` are removed. More details here:

[**Breaking change: `jQuery.event.props` and `jQuery.event.fixHooks` removed**](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-jquery-event-props-and-jquery-event-fixhooks-removed)

> jQuery's event handling performance increased thanks to a
>   reorganization of event property management. The main improvement is
>   that jQuery now only calculates or copies a property on the first
>   access, rather than calculating and copying them up front. This is a
>   really big win with properties that may force layout that the event
>   handler may not even need. The most common use we know of was to add
>   properties for pointer events, which is no longer necessary because
>   those events are supported already in jQuery 3.0. The jQuery Migrate
>   plugin provides support for these properties if you still need them.
>   The related but undocumented `mouseHooks` and `keyHooks` lists were
>   removed as well. The team is interested in understanding other use
>   cases before defining new APIs, so feel free to open a ticket.

The github issue is still open and no solution has been provided yet as of 08.01.2016. As an alternative fix you can either:-

- Use the jQuery Migrate plugin, which provides support for these
  properties.
- Or, use any jQuery version below 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.0 of jQuery Events Move now supports jQuery 3.x

http://stephen.band/jquery.event.move/

> *UPDATE 2.0.0*: `move` events are now compatible with jQuery 3.x. In addition, the underlying implementation is rewritten using vanilla DOM
>   (where before it was jQuery special events only) – jQuery is no longer
>   a requirement.