# Migrating angularJS directive using dataTransfer with Jquery.1.12.4 to Jquery.3.2.1

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have used the next angular drag and drop directive that I found here in other post.

To enable "dataTransfer" With Jquery  1.12.4, I have used:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But if I replace Jquery 1.12.4 with  jquery.3.2.1 I have the next error:

```
(index):104 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at (index):104
```

Is there some way to set dataTransfer with Jquery.3.2.1?

//angular directive

```
angular
  .module('clinang')
  .directive('dragMe', dragMe)
  .directive('dropOnMe', dropOnMe);

dragMe.$inject = [];

function typeInTextarea(el, newText) {
  var start = el.selectionStart
  var end = el.selectionEnd
  var text = el.value
  var before = text.substring(0, start)
  var after  = text.substring(end, text.length)
  el.value = (before + newText + after)
  el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = start + newText.length
  el.focus()
}

function dragMe() {
  var DDO = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.prop('draggable', true);
      element.on('dragstart', function(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.id)
      });
    }
  };
  return DDO;
}
dropOnMe.$inject = [];
function dropOnMe() {
  var DDO = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('dragover', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
      element.on('drop', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var x=document.getElementById(data);
        typeInTextarea(event.target,x.getAttribute('data-value'))
      });
    }
  };
  return DDO;
}
```

Comment: It was replaced with `event.addProp('dataTransfer')`. See examples in this question and this this comment in particular, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727019/how-to-use-jqlite-with-jquery-noconflict-to-make-it-available-with-jquery#comment72588553_42727019

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, my directive is working very well.